# Why is ACK message routed internally after adding Record-Route header to initial INVITE SIP message?

Tags: servlets, sip, telecommunication, jain-sip

Record-Route header is added to initial INVITE message shown as below. Upon receiving 
200 OK for this request, ACK is created by using createAck() method in SipServletResponse class. Output of ACK message is also shown as below. As you see,  47.168.150.15 is added to route header which is initially added to INVITE as Record-Route. Because of that ACK message is routed internally and it is not sent out to 47.168.22.204.

Below line is from mobicents debug logs.
[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.SipServletRequestImpl] The request is going internally due to RR = Route: ;lr

I must add Record-Route header to be able to receive subsequent messages for the session.

Do you have any idea why 47.168.150.15 is added to ACK message? I tried to remove this address from ACK and modify Record-Route header but I could not succeed.

Thanks in advance.
Hatke

```
INVITE sip:u6002@kk1ims1.com;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c377b8dc2fd0d30e500caf2e1dc96e52@10.15.3.11
CSeq: 1 INVITE
From: <sip:u6013@kk1ims1.com>;tag=80260627_0efbfc5e_83a50d35-38c8-44ff-be22-8e3d0a2213e5
To: <sip:u6002@kk1ims1.com>
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: "u6013" <sip:u6013@47.168.150.15:5060;transport=udp>
User-Agent: WAM 7.0
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,MESSAGE,NOTIFY,INFO
Route: <sip:10.15.3.11:5065;lr;transport=udp;node_host=10.15.3.11;node_port=5180>
Route: <sip:scscf@47.168.22.204:5060;lr;client-orig>
Record-Route: <sip:47.168.150.15:5060>;lr
P-Charging-Vector: icid-value="b0af7824-b589-4d8d-8048-0b5a98ecfbf61397028011061";orig-ioi="Type 1cscf1@homedomain.com"
P-Asserted-Identity: <sip:u6013@kk1ims1.com>
P-Visited-Network-ID: susoh-apims.ims.lab.centurylink
P-Access-Network-Info: ADSL; network-provided;dsl-location=SustainingLab1
Expires: 180
Content-Type: application/sdp
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 47.168.150.15:5060;branch=z9hG4bK83a50d35-38c8-44ff-be22-8e3d0a2213e5_0efbfc5e_402240429608258
Content-Length: 606


    SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.15.3.11:5180;branch=z9hG4bK83a50d35-38c8-44ff-be22-8e3d0a2213e5_0efbfc5e_402240429608258;received=10.15.3.11
To: "u6002 basic" <sip:u6002@kk1ims1.com>;tag=45-4b18-623c-ffffffff
From: "u6013 allowed_clients_nopccset" <sip:u6013@kk1ims1.com>;tag=80260627_0efbfc5e_83a50d35-38c8-44ff-be22-8e3d0a2213e5
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Call-ID: c377b8dc2fd0d30e500caf2e1dc96e52@10.15.3.11
P-Charging-Function-Addresses: ecf="aaa://node3.kk1ims1.com;transport=tcp";ecf="aaa://node4.kk1ims1.com;transport=tcp";ccf="aaa://node.kk1ims1.com;transport=tcp";ccf="aaa://node1.kk1ims1.com;transport=tcp"
Record-Route: <sip:47.168.116.57:5060;lr>
Record-Route: <sip:130e7466scscf@47.168.22.204:5060;lr>
Record-Route: <sip:47.168.150.15:5060>;lr
Contact: <sip:u6002@47.168.116.57:5060;nt_end_pt=YM0+~KuBj08~Yo1T.bEu10qrm02~Xn2rdk71cpice~HW2YK005Odke~EbtYMig~W3QbP1E5T548._4QQ4VPnkTn291eyw8TeVy1tmn-~V!04ta06Gtd1T05k;nt_server_host=47.168.116.57:5060>
Allow: ACK,MESSAGE,NOTIFY,INVITE,BYE,CANCEL,REFER,OPTIONS,INFO,PUBLISH,UPDATE
P-Charging-Vector: icid-value="b0af7824-b589-4d8d-8048-0b5a98ecfbf61397028011061"
Supported: replaces
User-Agent: A2PC 10.1.1109
Call-Info: <http://trsbrms15-2.netas.lab.nortel.com:8081/pa/direct/pictureServlet?user=u6002@kk1ims1.com>;Purpose=icon
Content-Type: application/sdp
x-nt-party-id: u6002/
x-nt-location: 4333
Content-Length: 438


ACK sip:u6002@47.168.116.57:5060;nt_end_pt=YM0+~KuBj08~Yo1T.bEu10qrm02~Xn2rdk71cpice~HW2YK005Odke~EbtYMig~W3QbP1E5T548._4QQ4VPnkTn291eyw8TeVy1tmn-~V!04ta06Gtd1T05k;nt_server_host=47.168.116.57:5060 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c377b8dc2fd0d30e500caf2e1dc96e52@10.15.3.11
CSeq: 1 ACK
From: <sip:u6013@kk1ims1.com>;tag=80260627_0efbfc5e_83a50d35-38c8-44ff-be22-8e3d0a2213e5
To: <sip:u6002@kk1ims1.com>;tag=45-4b18-623c-ffffffff
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:47.168.150.15:5060>;lr
Route: <sip:130e7466scscf@47.168.22.204:5060;lr>
Route: <sip:47.168.116.57:5060;lr>
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Check server.xml if there is an outbound load balancer in place. You must post full debug logs to see whats going on. Also is there any app routing? It's more of a sip servlet problem rather than jsip. Which versions do you use?

Comment: Hi, we use sip-servlets-impl 1.5. Maybe problem is solved in latest jar. What i did is to remove top most record route header in ACK message not route it internally. Hatke

Comment: Yes please update to the latest version. 1.5 is way too old.